# make a repeating background information fetch iOS

Tags: ios, swift, background, push-notification

How to **make a repeating background information fetch on iOS, or just a repeating action for a few moments?** For example, check info on some website every minute?

The things I have already tried / revealed:

- Just background fetch does not fit - it updates information with its own specific time period.
- Push notifications: which existing services allow to do this? Or
- should I install my own scripts and run them periodically using the things like Cron?

So, what can be suggested to solve this problem? I use Swift

Thanks!

Comment: just use a timer....

Comment: You can use a timer if you are only talking about when your app is in the foreground. If you want background support then background fetch is the approach. Aggressively polling is bad for network use and battery life. Push notifications are a better approach

Comment: Ah didn't realize they had said background information. Well then absolutely don't use a timer haha